# css: inline elements with different borders on hover, weird alignment

Tags: html, css, layout, border

I want to have 3 elements in line.. a round icon for the step number, the title and an optional icon on the far right, separated by a vertical line.

The issue is with the bottom border. Because the bottom border "enlarges" the element, there is a gap in the bottom of the border between the vertical border and the bottom border... (and in fact, in my production code, the border bottom on hover DOES line up with the border-bottom of the container, however, the vertical border still has a gap at the bottom equal to the thickness of the border-bottom of the icon-button.

See the fiddle below:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wdvVBX

**HTML**

```
<div class="step-container">
  <h2 class="step-title">
    <div class="round-icon">
      3
    </div>
    <span class="title">Migration</span>
  </h2>
  <div class="icon-button">
    <i class="fa fa-print"></i>

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.step {

}

.step-container { 
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.step-title {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2rem 0 2rem 2rem;
}

.round-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2reml;
  line-height: 2rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.icon-button {
  float: right;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  height: 100%;

}
.icon-button:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `::after` pseudo element instead of border.
http://codepen.io/meecrobe/pen/pPoMZo

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it like this: display flex on step-container and margin-left: auto for the icon-button with the height:100% and float:right removed